# Cannot access GKE with static external IP

Tags: gke-networking

I am trying to assign static external IP to the GKE LB.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: onesg
  labels:
    app: onesg
spec:
  selector:
    app: onesg
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: "my regional IP"
```

But after deployment, I cannot access my app from the regional IP. Any idea?

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.104.0.1      <none>          443/TCP        23h
onesg        LoadBalancer   10.104.15.191   my regional IP  80:31293/TCP  7m18s
```

If I use ephemeral IP assigned by GKE LB, I can access my app.

Comment: check the load balancer that was created in GCP console, does it also have the same IP assigned to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if your Service is actually pointing to the proper pods.

run the following

```
kubectl describe service onesg
```

in the output there should be a field called endpoints.

run this

kubectl get pods -o wide

and make sure the list of IP's in the endpoint field from the first command matches the IP of the pods from the second one

Next to troubleshoot you can try to make sure you app works, you can do that by using the kubectl port-forward command

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/

Comment: Thanks, I retried few times and eventually it worked by keying in the regional IP in the URL, not clicking the link in GCP console....